# Receiving PDUs that are sent over a network, and filtering them as received before displaying to user

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following Java method, which I am trying to use to filter PDU messages that are received over a network, and display only the PDUs which match the filter criteria to the user:

```
public static void displayFilteredPdu(){
    try{
        EspduReceiver.socket = new MulticastSocket(EspduSender.PORT);
        EspduReceiver.address = InetAddress.getByName(EspduSender.DEFAULT_MULTICAST_GROUP);
        EspduReceiver.socket.joinGroup(EspduReceiver.address); 



        while(EspduReceiver.stopCapture == false){
            byte buffer[] = new byte[EspduReceiver.MAX_PDU_SIZE];
            EspduReceiver.packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            EspduReceiver.socket.receive(EspduReceiver.packet);

            Pdu pdu = EspduReceiver.pduFactory.createPdu(EspduReceiver.packet.getData());

            if(pdu != null){
                System.out.print("Got PDU of type: " + pdu.getClass().getName());
                if(pdu instanceof EntityStatePdu){
                    EntityID eid = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityID(); 
                    Vector3Double position = ((EntityStatePdu)pdu).getEntityLocation(); 
                    System.out.println(" EID:[" + eid.getSite() + ", " + eid.getApplication() + ", " + eid.getEntity() + "] ");
                    System.out.println("Location in DIS coordinates: [" + position.getX() + ", " + position.getY() + ", " + position.getZ() + "] ");
                    /*Add PDU to ArrayList of PDUs */
                    EspduReceiver.espdu.add(pdu);
    /*              System.out.println(" PDU added to arrayList. "); 
                    System.out.println(espdu); /*This is printing out the actual DIS messages (i.e. edu.nps.moves.dis.EntityState...),
                    maybe try adding the 'eid.getSite()', etc to an ArrayList instead. Use Associative arrays/ map/ hashmap */

                //  if(eid.getSite() != 0){
                        Filter.sitesToBeFiltered.add(eid.getSite());
                        System.out.println("Entity Site added to ArrayList. ");
                //  } else if(eid.getApplication() != 0){
                    Filter.applicationsToBeFiltered.add(eid.getApplication());
                    System.out.println("Entity Application added to ArrayList. ");
                    Filter.IDsToBeFiltered.add(eid.getEntity());
                    System.out.println("Entity ID added to ArrayList");
                    Filter.positionsToBeFilteredX.add(position.getX());
                    System.out.println("Entity X position added to ArrayList. ");
                    Filter.positionsToBeFilteredY.add(position.getY());
                    System.out.println("Entity Y position added to ArrayList. ");
                    Filter.positionsToBeFilteredZ.add(position.getZ());
                    System.out.println("Entity Z position added to ArrayList. ");

                    int i;
                    getFilterConditions();
                    for(i = 0; i < sitesToBeFiltered.size(); i++){
                        if(sitesToBeFiltered.get(i) == filter1Value){
                            //public double xPos = new Double();
                            Gui.displayFilteredOutput.append("\n");
                            Gui.displayFilteredOutput.append("EID: [" + sitesToBeFiltered.get(i) + ", " + applicationsToBeFiltered.get(i) + ", " + IDsToBeFiltered.get(i) + "]. ");
                            double filteredX = positionsToBeFilteredX.get(i);
                            double filteredY = positionsToBeFilteredY.get(i);
                            double filteredZ = positionsToBeFilteredZ.get(i);
                            //Vector3Double filteredEntityPosition = 
                            Gui.displayFilteredOutput.append("\n Location in DIS coordinates: [" + filteredX + ":" + filteredY + ":" + filteredZ + "]. ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in displayFilteredPdu() method. ");
        /*09/04/2014 @ 17:100
         * If this exception gets called, presumably it either means that pdu is not an instance of EntityStatePdu, or
         * that pdu does not actually hold a packet.  */
    }

}
```

This method is currently in a class called Filter.java, and is called when the user clicks a 'Filter' button on the GUI, and will continue to be called until the value of the variable `stopCapture` is changed to false (which will happen when the user clicks a 'stop' button on the GUI).

However, it is not quite behaving as I was hoping when called at the moment: currently, when the user clicks the 'Filter' button, all of the `System.out.println` statements are displayed in the console, so clearly the `while` loop is being entered, but I don't see anything displayed in the GUI, which I think would indicate that the `for` loop at the end of the `while` loop is not being entered... and also, the GUI stops responding...

As I understand, the reason that the GUI stops responding is probably because I am currently using a single threaded program, and so moving this `displayFilteredPdu()` method to another thread might stop the GUI from crashing, and I can then work on the other issues with the method.

I have tried doing this by moving the method to another class (called FilteredPdu.java), which extends Filter, and changing the button `ActionListener()` to call the method from the new class, i.e. `FilteredPdu.displayFilteredPdu();`, but I am still getting the same problem with the GUI crashing.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: For starters, break out your filter into its own method (or class) and test it independently. There's way too much going on in that method to easily troubleshoot it.

Comment: The method above is in its own class- and testing it independently is exactly what I'm trying to do... It's not actually doing all that much at the moment, just listening on the network for any PDUs- every time it hears one, it will get some of its information, add that information to a set of ArrayLists, and print a few lines in the console saying that it has done so. (That's everything before the 'for' loop). Once it reaches the 'for' loop, it should then loop through one of the ArrayLists that it's just populated, checking each element to see if it matches the value of a JTextArea...

Comment: If it does, it should print some more information in another JTextArea... but it's not doing that last part at all at the moment, and for some reason, it's crashing.

Comment: No, that method is running networking, decoding, filtering, and displaying all in one single glop. Break it down into simple pieces and connect them up once each is working.

Answer (score 1):

i think moving it in another class will still cause your program to be stuck in infinite loop.
try and make a class the extends Thread, put display filter pdu method as:

this is the new thread class:

```
public class YourThreadClass  extends Thread{
    String fake_input_in_thread = null;

    public YourThreadClass(String fake_input){
        //constructor
        //save the input / whatever you need to pass in from the other class here, and use it later
        fake_input_in_thread = fake_input
    }

    public void run() {
        //your filter code
        try{
            //now you can use the value pass-in from you main class. This should display "testing123" in console.
            System.out.println(fake_input_in_thread);

            EspduReceiver.socket = new MulticastSocket(EspduSender.PORT);
            EspduReceiver.address = InetAddress.getByName(EspduSender.DEFAULT_MULTICAST_GROUP);
            EspduReceiver.socket.joinGroup(EspduReceiver.address); 
            .............................
    }

    //put the below method into the thread class
    public void endOfFilter(){
        EspduReceiver.stopCapture = false;
    }
}
```

when you GUI needs to trigger that method, here's what your main class will looks like

```
//initialize 
YourThreadClass thread = null;

public static void displayFilteredPdu(){
    if(thread ==null){
        //This string is to demostrate how you'd pass variables into your custom class, does not have any actual use
        String str = "testing123";

        thread = new YourThreadClass(str);
        thread.start();
    }
}

//in main code
public static void stopFilteredPdu(){
    if(thread != null){
        thread.endOfFilter();
        thread = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer- I've started giving your suggestion a go, but I'm not sure if I understand correctly... when you say put my filter code inside the `run()` method, do you mean put the whole filter method in there, so that I have a nested method? i.e. `public void run(){ public static void displayFilteredPdu(){...}}` I tried that, but a syntax error that says `Syntax error on token "void", @ expected`. It also then means that I cannot call the `displayFilteredPdu()` method from Gui.java, although I can solve that by doing `FilteredPdu.run()` instead. Any solutions for compile errors?

Comment: check out the updated answer. This should be easier to read i hope. This might not work 100% and you probably need to iron out the rest out. it would be a good training thou. Good luck :D

Comment: Hey, thanks for the updated answer- I'll try giving it a go now. Just one quick question: I'm not sure what input I should be putting in the parenthesis where you've said "input_that_you_need"- what should I be passing as parameters there?

Comment: Ok, so I've tried what you've suggested (but left the parenthesis that I mentioned a moment ago empty, as I'm not sure what to put in them), but I get a compile error on the line `thread.endOfFilter();` that says "The method endOfFilter() is undefined for the type Thread". I have defined that method just above the call to it with `public void endOfFilter(){ EspduReceiver.stopCapture = false; }`... The quick fix that it's suggesting is to "Add cast to thread".

Comment: It might be a bit late to answer you, but clearly you have a lot to learn in term of simply java concepts/syntex. I won't be able to hold your hands foever and this is probably the last time I can help. I've updated the code with the class name, see if that help.

Comment: also, answering the problem you have with the "input_that_you_need" question. That is just a opening that I left for you for the thread class. Sometime you might need some kind of variable/information from your main class but you couldn't access it inside your custom thread class, so you might need to pass those values/variables into the thread class when you initiate the thread class so you can use it later. I've made a fake example so you know what I meant.